# How to pass data when instantiating a Fragment since I can't override the constructor?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I have a FragmentPageAdapter and I want it to load the same fragment with different values instead of various fragments.
This values is just 1 string. How do I pass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple example on how to do it:

```
// in the adapter
private static final String[] VALUES = { 
   "string 1", 
   "string 2", 
   "string 3", 
   "string 4", 
   "string 5",  };

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    MyFrag f = new MyFrag();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("value", VALUES[position]);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}

// then in the fragment 
private String value;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   value = getArguments.getString("value");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Bundle` (fragment argument) for it. See example:

```
//put yours info to Bundle
Bundle bundl = new Bundle();
bundl.putString("key", "value");
//set bundle to frgments arguments
YoursFragClass frag = new YoursFragClass();
frag.setArguments(bundl);
//add fragment to activity
...
```

Yours info in `Bundle` will appear as argument of `Fragments` livecycle methods

```
//then in fragments `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` you receive this Bundle as argument
public class YoursFragClass extends Fragment {

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
         ViewGroup containerObject,
         Bundle savedInstanceState){
         //here is your arguments
         Bundle bundle=getArguments(); 

        //here is yours info
        String myString = bundle.getString("key");
        System.out.println(myString); //will show "value" in logCat
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use arguments for that.

They are represented as a `Bundle` and are set via `setArguments()`. Bear in mind they can only be set before the fragment has been attached to an activity.

For convenience, you can create a factory method for your fragment to hide the complexity of creating the bundle:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static MyFragment getInstance(<the instantiation parameters here>) {

        // check parameter preconditions
        final Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        // put parameters into the bundle
        final MyFragment instance = new MyFragment();
        instance.setArguments(arguments);
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Another benefit of using arguments is that they are kept if the fragment instance is being recreated.